# Why am I getting a 404 error when I run this using Flask Run?

Tags: http-status-code-404

> ````
> extends "layout.html" %}
> block content %}
>     <div class="content-section">
>         <form method="POST" action="">
> form.hidden_tag() }}
>                 <fieldset class="form-group">
>                     <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Join Today</legend>
>                     <div class="form-group">
> form.username.label (class="form-control-label") }}
> form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="form-group">
> form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
> form.email(class="form-control-lg") }}
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="form-group">
> form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
> form.password(class="form-control-lg" ) }}
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="form-group">
> form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
> form.confirm_password(class="form-control-lg") }}
>                     </div>
>                 </fieldset>
>                     <div class="form-group">
> form.submit (class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
>                     </div>
>         </form> 
>     <div>
>             <div class="border-top pt-3"> 
>                     <small class="text-muted">
> Already Have an Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In </a>
>                     </small>
>             </div>
> endblock content %}```
> ````
>
> app.route("/register")
> def register():
> form = RegistrationForm()
> return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)

I have pretty much tried to fix all the issues and tried to change any errors in the code that I might have made. For some reason the first two routes that I made are working fine. The issue could have been from the extend layout.html code block since the layout.html might not be fomratted correctly and I have not checked that extensively, but that is why I am asking you guys for help.